# Drawing a horizontal line till first candlestock

Tags: highcharts

I want to plot a horizontal line starting from the right but then stopping at the first candlestick.

I am showing what I managed to do till now in image below (had to include a link rather than an image) but I do not wish that the line goes through all the candlesticks since I might be having more than one candlestick in the same graph. So I wish to that the line stops at the very first candlestick and does not go through all the candlesticks.

http://s17.postimg.org/luvox5ugf/rightyaxis.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can use plotLines for yAxis

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.plotLines